# Search Specific Duplicated keys in List C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I Have list named "listA" contain 1 field named "fieldA" and the data are

```
{1,0,0,0,1}
```

I want to detect if there is duplication in "1" only, but  if "0" duplicated, it's will not count as duplicate

I try

```
 var dupl = listA
                            .GroupBy(i => i.fieldA=="1")
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
 if (dupl.Count()>0){"you have duplicated 1"}
```

but "0" still detected as duplicated, what is wrong with my linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to know is whether there are duplicates of 1 then just use `Count`:

```
bool isDuplicate = listA.Count(x => x.fieldA == "1") > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
bool oneIsDuplicate = listA.Where(x=>x.fieldA=="1").Count() > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one might be helpful.
Here we avoid the extra iterations when the condition is met before the end of the collection is reached.(we don't iterate the entire collection in case the condition is met before the end of the collection and therefore it's a bit more 
tuned up performance wise).

```
public static class Extentions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to find if an local variable aggreation based condition is met in a collection of items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TItem">Collection items' type.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TLocal">Local variable's type.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">Inspected collection of items.</param>
        /// <param name="initializeLocalVar">Returns local variale initial value.</param>
        /// <param name="changeSeed">Returns desired local variable after each iteration.</param>
        /// <param name="stopCondition">Prediate to stop the method execution if collection hasn't reached last item.</param>
        /// <returns>Was stop condition reached before last item in collection was reached.</returns>
        /// <example> 
        ///  var numbers = new []{1,2,3};
        ///  bool isConditionMet = numbers.CheckForLocalVarAggreatedCondition(
        ///                                             () => 0, // init
        ///                                             (a, i) => i == 1 ? ++a : a, // change local var if condition is met 
        ///                                             (a) => a > 1);   
        /// </example>
        public static bool CheckForLocalVarAggreatedCondition<TItem, TLocal>(
                                this IEnumerable<TItem> source,
                                Func<TLocal> initializeLocalVar,
                                Func<TLocal, TItem, TLocal> changeSeed,
                                Func<TLocal, bool> stopCondition)
        {
            TLocal local = default(TLocal);
            foreach (TItem item in source)
            {
                local = changeSeed(local, item);
                if (stopCondition(local))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```